# Shifting Bits by Value in Register

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, att

I have %ecx containing the number of places I want the value of %esi to be shifted to the left, but to my understanding the source of shl must be an immediate value.

Can someone help me understand how I would go about shifting by the value of %ecx? I've looked around and have seen people recommend the usage of the CL register. But is there an alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 80386 architecture provides a left-shift instruction with the shift amount in `%cl` which is masked with 31 for dword shifts, 15 for word shifts, etc.  Note that the `%cl` register is the lowest 8 bits of the `%ecx` register:

```
0       8       16              32                              64
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| rcx                                                           |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| ecx                           |
+---------------+---------------+
| cx            |
+-------+-------+
| cl    | ch    |
+-------+-------+
```

Therefore, `shll %cl,%esi` already does what you expect and shifts the content of `%esi` by the number of places specified in `%ecx` as the high bits don't really matter anyway (the shift amount is masked with 31 before shifting).

Comment: ...or masked by 63 for 64-bit registers

Comment: The high bits may in fact matter for the program, in which case special care must be taken to zero out the result. You might expect `1 << 33` to be `0` not `2`.

Comment: @Jester That's correct. However, since shll masks the shift operand with 31, it doesn't matter if any high bits are set in ecx as they are masked out anyway.

Comment: That's exactly the point: the masking done by `shl` turns `33` into `1`, thereby giving incorrect result. So if you **do** want correct result, you have to check yourself.

Comment: @Jester Yes. Though, I don't see how this is relevant to the question “how can I have the shift amount in ecx instead of cl?”

Comment: That's not the question though. OP said he already has the shift count in `ecx`, which may very well be above `31`, so blindly using `cl` instead may give wrong result.

Comment: @fuz shifting by `ecx` would be pointless, since after 9, 17, 33 etc rotates (according to target) would do the same as 1 shift. BTW the `cl` shift was in 8086 architecture. It was provided because the immediate operand could only be `1`.

Comment: @Jester Anyway; I have amended the answer. I hope it addresses your concerns.

Comment: Not really, but who am I to complain :)  I find this misleading: _"shifts the content of %esi by the number of places specified in %ecx"_. The high bits do not matter for the `shl` instruction but might for the program. `ecx` may very well be the result of a calculation where you don't know if it's gonna be <32 or not and you might expect the correct result in any case. Producing `x<<1` instead of `x<<33` is not correct.

Comment: @Jester That's why I have amended my answer to say “which is masked with...”

Comment: ...my comment was faulty. For the left shift in the question any value of `ecx` above `cl` if allowed would shift out bits that were already shifted out by the value in `cl`. And an immediate shift operand > 1 was introduced in 80186.

Comment: @WeatherVane They won't because the amounts of shifts is masked by 31.

Comment: It wasn't masked on the 8086, which is what I think @WeatherVane was talking about. Masking of the input in `cl` wasn't introduced until the 286. Of course, even though there was no form of the shift instructions that took immediate operands, no one actually used `cl` for this purpose, as it was faster to use a series of shift-by-implicit-1 instructions.

Comment: @fuz x86 masks with 31 (lower 5 bits) for all data sizes of 8, 16, 32 bits. This is explicitly documented and can be easily checked with tests. Also, `%cl` is lowest 8 bits, not 32 (seems typo).